# Translate magento attribute php code

Tags: php, magento

I am not a great programmer but want to translate my Dutch attributes on the category overview page. Currently it's like this:

**Current Dutch attribute names :**

[image]

Now I would like to translate "`Merk`" for example in the German version "`Marke`". I coded it like this:

```
    <div class="price-box">

    <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('merk') != ''):  ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock opties" 
                style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:8px;">
        <?php echo $this->__('■ Merk:') ?>
        <span>
            <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('merk') ?>
        </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('supdoelgroep') != ''):  ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock opties" 
                 style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom:8px;">
        <?php echo $this->__('■ Voor:') ?>
        <span>
            <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('supdoelgroep') ?>
        </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Does anyone know the php codes so I can fill in the translation per storeview?

Comment: You should try attribute translation by admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to used magento default translate functionality.

For This :

```
<?php echo $this->__('Merk') ?>
```

Add like:

```
app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Mage_Catalog.csv
```

add value in this csv file like,

```
"Merk","Marke"
```